# How to navigate to current child state with different parameters

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

Here's the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/challenger/622qzqsc/

I have an intermediate **abstract state**, which serves as timeline builder. Here at its template I use (*which is incorrect*) the `ui-sref=".({year: year})"` call.

I expected that the dot **'.'** in **ui-sref** would reflect the current child state I was standing on instead of the abstract state itself.

Is it possible to navigate to `main.list.movies` state (**to self**) picking a different year parameter from `main.list` state / view?

Answer (score 0):

Use `.movies` with parameters `{year: year}`, which will redirect to same state with different parameter. Where `.` means based on parent state it will find a child state to navigate.

```
ui-sref=".movies({year: year})"
```

[**Forked Plunkr**](https://jsfiddle.net/8nuLyrky/)

Comment: I understand that. But *movies* and *presentations* share the same **`main.list`** state / view.

Comment: I'm wondering if there's something working as a placeholder for either movies / presentations, like that **`ui-sref=".$myCurrentChildState({year: year})"`**

Comment: @lexeme got it, you mean to say that, you don't want to mention state name while navigating same state? correct me if I'm wrong...

Comment: yes, this is what I want. But you should consider that the **`ui-sref="..."`** (link) resides inside the **`main.list`** view.